# launch file: parameters via -- (double dash) don't go well with commenting

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a rqt being loaded with a custom perspective, see:

```
<node name="my_rqt_dashboard" pkg="rqt_gui" type="rqt_gui" respawn="false" output="screen" 
    args="--perspective-file $(find my_rospkg)/cfg/viz/asdf.perspective"/>
```

My "problem" is that commenting out that line breaks the xml, as double hyphen are not allowed in comments, see [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842131/xml-comments-and/10846561).
A workaround is to use  `&#45;&#45;` instead of `--`, but that is kind of ugly.
Any other ideas? Unfortunately, the `--perspective-file` does not seem to have a single hyphen equivalent, e.g. `-q`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391521/launch-file:-parameters-via----(double-dash)-don%27t-go-well-with-commenting/) by [ticotico](https://answers.ros.org/users/58821/ticotico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2021-11-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on 2021-11-25**:
I put a space in between the two hyphens, so I have `<!-- - -perspective-file -->`. In my particular case it's a `gdb` command line, and luckily its argument parser interprets `- -foo` as `--foo`, so I don't need to remember to remove the space when commenting back in. FYI, this is my usual way for debugging a crashing node `<!-- launch-prefix="xterm -e gdb -ex 'catch throw' -ex 'catch syscall 60' -ex run - -args" -->`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There seems to be a way to make comments like this.

```
<?ignore
<node name="my_rqt_dashboard" pkg="rqt_gui" type="rqt_gui" respawn="false" output="screen" 
    args="--perspective-file $(find my_rospkg)/cfg/viz/asdf.perspective"/>
?>
```

( `<?ignore <stuff> ?>`, and `<stuff>` is said to be a comment. )

ref : https://norlab.ulaval.ca/research/how-to-comment-lauch-file/

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2021-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ticotico](https://answers.ros.org/users/58821/ticotico/) on 2021-11-24**:
nice, thx a lot! too bad that there is no out of the box shortcut for that...